# How to extract Indexed Variable information in pyomo Model and build Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, variables, multi-index, pyomo

I am attempting to solve a MIP using Pyomo with several Indexed Variables of different sizes. What I would like to do is export the results of the variables to a dataframe so that I can further analyze these results. My problem is that I cannot figure out a way to nicely automate the process as the size of the Indexed Variables can change in each model simulation.

Here is an example of some variables I would create:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.T = pyo.RangeSet(0, 10)
model.Generators = pyo.Set(initialize=(['equip_1', 'equip_2']))
model.Storages = pyo.Set(initialize=(['storage_1', 'storage_2']))

model.var_1 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Generators, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_2 = pyo.Var(model.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_3 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Storages, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_4 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Generators, domain=pyo.Binary, initialize=0)

# constraints and objective function here, which I don't think are relevant for the question
.
.
.
SolverFactory('cbc').solve(model).write()
```

Now, I want to create the dataframe with model.T as the index and the variable name plus the model.Generator or model.Storages as a multiIndex column (I am assuming it would have to be a multiIndex, but perhaps not). A crude example of how I want it to look is shown below:

```
  |      Var_1      | Var_2 |        Var_3        |      Var_4
  | equip_1 equip_2 | None  | storage_1 storage_2 | equip_1 equip_2
m |   0    |   0    |   0   |     0     |   0     |   0    |   1  
o |   1    |   1    |   1   |     1     |   1     |   1    |   0  
d |   2    |   2    |   2   |     2     |   2     |   0    |   1  
e |   3    |   3    |   3   |     3     |   3     |   1    |   0  
l |   4    |   4    |   4   |     4     |   4     |   0    |   1  
. |   5    |   5    |   5   |     5     |   5     |   1    |   0  
T |   6    |   6    |   6   |     6     |   6     |   0    |   1
```

The values shown are just examples. Also, the model.T doesn't have to be the index as it would correlate to a standard index created with a dataframe.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work but I am struggling to find the right syntax in pyomo. I feel there must be an easy way to extract this data as I can't be the first one trying to do this but I've searched the internet to no avail for this specific problem. The problem I have is trying to extract the variable index (model.T and model.Generators/Storages) from the variable results in an easy loop or vectorized fashion.

Please! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I haven't made this clear enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Totally doable...

First, let's cover a basic example of how to (in the general sense) get the results out of `pyomo` after a solve.  Recall, that after the solver completes, the optimal values of the variables will be loaded into the model variables.  Here is a cheap example that shows 3 ways to extract data from the variables.  There are many others, depending on what needs to be done.  Of note, the last method here, converting to a dictionary, is key to transitioning over to `pandas` because we all know pandas love dictionaries.

```
# extracting values 1
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('value extraction')

m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=range(3))
m.X = pyo.Var(m.S, initialize={0:-1, 1:2.5, 2:12})   # just initializing to simulate solving

# show all of X
m.X.display()

# iterate through and show values
print()
for s in m.S:
    print(f'for index {s} X[{s}] is: {m.X[s].value}')

# dump into a dictionary.... an entry point for pandas!
print()
print(m.X.extract_values())

# make a pd.Series indexed by the index set(s)
print()
x_vals = pd.Series(m.X.extract_values(), name=m.X.name)
print(x_vals)
```

#### Yields:

```
X : Size=3, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :  None :    -1 :  None : False : False :  Reals
      1 :  None :   2.5 :  None : False : False :  Reals
      2 :  None :    12 :  None : False : False :  Reals

for index 0 X[0] is: -1
for index 1 X[1] is: 2.5
for index 2 X[2] is: 12

{0: -1, 1: 2.5, 2: 12}

0    -1.0
1     2.5
2    12.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

### Part II:

Ok, on to building a more comprehensive solution to your challenge of mashing the whole result into a multi-indexed dataframe.  Of note, I *only* initialized the values of the variables in this to simulate solving.  Normally, not needed for variables.

So this builds on the concept before, which is that a `pd.Series` is just an array that is indexed by an index array, and can be constructed from dictionaries.  I'm not the slickest `pandas` operator, so there may be some way to combine some of the `pd` commands, but who cares?  This is step-by-step and if you are dealing with variables from an optimization, it is not going to be too huge, so tweaking is unnecessary.

```
# extracting values 2
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.T = pyo.RangeSet(0, 10)
model.Generators = pyo.Set(initialize=(['equip_1', 'equip_2']))
model.Storages = pyo.Set(initialize=(['storage_1', 'storage_2']))

model.var_1 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Generators, initialize=1.5, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_2 = pyo.Var(model.T, initialize=2.5, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_3 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Storages, initialize=3.5, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.var_4 = pyo.Var(model.T, model.Generators, domain=pyo.Binary, initialize=0)

#model.display()

# let's convert each var to a pandas series, indexed by model.T...

# get all the variables (assuming the fuller model will have constraints, params, etc.)
model_vars = model.component_map(ctype=pyo.Var)


serieses = []   # collection to hold the converted "serieses"
for k in model_vars.keys():   # this is a map of {name:pyo.Var}
    v = model_vars[k]

    # make a pd.Series from each    
    s = pd.Series(v.extract_values(), index=v.extract_values().keys())

    # if the series is multi-indexed we need to unstack it...
    if type(s.index[0]) == tuple:  # it is multi-indexed
        s = s.unstack(level=1)
    else:
        s = pd.DataFrame(s)         # force transition from Series -> df
    #print(s)

    # multi-index the columns
    s.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(k, t) for t in s.columns])

    serieses.append(s)

df = pd.concat(serieses, axis=1)
print(df)
```

#### Yields

```
     var_1         var_2     var_3             var_4        
   equip_1 equip_2     0 storage_1 storage_2 equip_1 equip_2
0      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
1      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
2      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
3      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
4      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
5      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
6      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
7      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
8      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
9      1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
10     1.5     1.5   2.5       3.5       3.5       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AirSquid this is perfect! You just made my week.